# I need to replace the placeholder in this input field

Tags: javascript, input, placeholder

I'm trying to replace this placeholder that says 'Search for...' to something else. The problem is - the input doesn't load for a while and I can't figure out how to detect when the input has loaded. Here's the page link so you can see how its loading https://asahouston.org/membership/member-directory/

Here's what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to be detecting the input field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("load", function(){
        document.getElementsByClassName(".SFfndtag input[type=text]").placeholder = "Search for Company Name...";
    }
</script>
```

I've tried a couple other things, but my javascript skills are lacking. I would appreciate any help you're able to provide. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you are using [getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) wrong. [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
document.addEvenlistener('load'...
```

to

```
window.adEventListener('load'...
```

**window.onload**

By default, it is fired when the entire page loads, including its    content (images, css, scripts, etc.) In some browsers it now takes   over the role of document.onload and fires when the DOM is ready as  well.

**document.onload**

It is called when the DOM is ready which can be prior to images and other external content is loaded.

--- EDIT ---

Definitly not the most elegant but this should do the trick.

```
var changePlaceholderInterval = setInterval(function () {changePlaceholder()}, 100);

function changePlaceholder() {
    if(document.querySelector('.SFfndtag input')){
        document.querySelector('.SFfndtag input').placeholder = "Search for Company Name...";
        window.clearInterval(changePlaceholderInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Overwriting the `onload` event is never a good idea. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Here's what I've tried 'window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
   var mrVariable = document.querySelector(".SFfndtag input[type=text]");
      window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
      mrVariable.innerHTML = "changed content";
  },false);' the return in console is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null' which tells me that window.addEventListener isn't loading after all the content loads - it looks like its loading before.

Comment: @GordonSmith I have edited my answer above with a new solution which should do the trick for you.

Comment: @ChrisWright This did it. Perfect! Thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use attr for JQuery or setAttribute for Javascript:

**JQuery**

```
 $('.SFfndtag').attr("placeholder", "Search for Company Name...");
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("SFfndtag").setAttribute("placeholder","Search for Company Name...");
```

Hope it helped you.